# Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sin\theta)$ is a field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

**QUESTION:**

> Show that $F_{\theta}=\mathbb{Q}(\sin\theta); \theta\in\mathbb{R}$ is a field. Moreover, Show that $E_{\theta}=\mathbb{Q}(\sin\frac{\theta}{3}); \theta\in\mathbb{R}$ is a field extension of $F_{\theta}$ and find the maximum value of [$E_{\theta}:F_{\theta}$]

I am unable to show that for every $x\in F_{\theta}$, it has an inverse.
Also, I have shown that for some specific values of $\theta$, $E_{\theta}$ is a field extension of $F_{\theta}$.
But I can't prove for a general $\theta$.

Comment: What does $\Bbb Q(\sin\theta)$ mean to you? Because to me, it is _by definition_ a field. The literal meaning of those symbols in my book is "The smallest subfield of $\Bbb R$ which contains $\Bbb Q$ and $\sin\theta$".

Comment: @Arthur I mean that I am unable to find the inverse for every $x\neq 0$ $\in F_{\theta}$

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb{Q}(\sin\theta)$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sin\theta):=\{a+b\sin\theta|a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Comment: @Kumar Yeah, that's not going to be a field most of the time. And it's not the standard definition of $\Bbb Q(\sin\theta)$. Are you _certain_ that that's your definition? I mean, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ _looks_ like that, for instance, but it's not usually _defined_ that way.

Comment: Sorry, but what you defined will be a field only if $\sin\theta$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree at most $2$. This is not even close to being true for all $\theta$.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry for the confusion, but we were given the definition as $\mathbb{F}(X):=\{a+bX|a,b\in \mathbb{F}\}$. I will check with the instructor.

Comment: Maybe you defined it specifically for elements like $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Kumar Arthur and Mark are right. I gave an explanation of what they said by editing my answer.

Comment: Is your set even closed with respect to multiplication? In particular, how were you able to express $\sin^2\theta$ as a linear expression in $\sin\theta$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\forall x\in\mathbb R, \sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$.

**Edit:** Didn't see your first question concerning inverses in $F_\theta$, my bad. As Arthur said in comment, $\mathbb Q(\sin(\theta))$ should be by definition the smallest field containing $\mathbb Q$ and $\sin(\theta)$. Also for some values of $\theta$, $\sin(\theta)$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb Q$. Hence for such a value $\theta$, you can't express $\dfrac{1}{\sin(\theta)}$ as a $\mathbb Q$-linear combinaision of powers of $\sin(\theta)$.

**Edit 2:** (See Edit 3 for mistakes) The definition you gave in comments <s>is the one for Q[sin(theta)]</s>. It is only normal that you struggle to show that it is a field, because in fact it is <s>a field if and only if $\sin(\theta)$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, otherwise it's merely an integral domain</s>. For example, if you take $\theta\in\mathbb R$ such that $\sin(\theta)=e^{-1}$, then knowing that $e^{-1}$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, then $\dfrac{1}{\sin(\theta)}=e\notin\mathbb Q[e^{-1}]$, because otherwise there exists a polynomial $P(X)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$ such that $P(e^{-1})=e$, and by multiplying in both sides of the expression with a high enough power of $e$, you get $Q(e)=1$ for some polynomial $Q(X)\in\mathbb Q[X]$, which contradicts the transcendence of $e$ over $\mathbb Q$.

**Edit 3:** As Mark said in comment, the definition you gave doesn't even make the structure a ring, and the smallest ring containing it is $\mathbb Q[\sin(\theta)]:=\{P(\sin\theta)\mid P(X)\in\mathbb Q[X]\}$ where $\mathbb Q[X]$ is the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$. As for $\{a+b\sin\theta\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$, all that can be said in a general matter about it ($\theta\in\mathbb R$ arbitrary) is that it is a $\mathbb Q$-vector space, of dimension $1$ if $\sin\theta\in\mathbb Q$, and $2$ otherwise.

Comment: Using the above identity only, I was successful in showing the extension, for specific values of $\theta$.

Comment: @Kumar I think it depends on how you understand what $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is for $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. Normally $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is by definition the smallest field containing $\mathbb Q$ and $\alpha$. Please see the edit above as to why you may struggle for some values of $\theta$.

Comment: Actually this is not even a definition for $\mathbb{Q}[\sin(\theta)]$. Let's assume it is a ring, then $\sin^2(\theta)$ has to be there. But then we can write $\sin^2(\theta)=a+b\sin(\theta)$, so $\sin(\theta)$ must be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree at most $2$. So if $\sin\theta$ is transcendental or even algebraic of a higher degree then $\{a+b\sin\theta:a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ will not be closed to multiplication.

Comment: @Mark Woops you're right. Thank you for pointing that out! Gonna fix it.

Answer (score 1):

$sin(\theta)=3sin(\theta/3)-4sin^3(\theta/3)$
so $[E_\theta:F_\theta]\leq 3$
to show that max = 3, let $\theta=30^\circ$
$1/2=sin(30^\circ)=3sin(10^\circ)-4sin^3(10^\circ)$
$8x^3-6x+1=0$ does not have rational roots by the rational root theorem, so it is irreducible.
$[E_{30^\circ}:F_{30^\circ}] = 3$

Comment: the question title is misleading; the crux of the qn is more like: what is the maximum value of the degree of the field extension?